# windows 7 taskbar icons moves by group (grouping is disabled)

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, icons

I have win 7. Taksbar grouping - "never"
All tasks(icons) are not in one small group, but big tasks as it must be.
But if I open 3 notepad programs etc & then I'll try to move one of this task in the left - windows move all 3 like one group. How to split them? It use to be splited.. and now its groupd.. somehow :(

many tnx for any help

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Taskbar option to 'Never Combine' does not effect on the behaviour of the icons when moving them on the Taskbar, it simply prevents icons for the same application from being 'stacked'.

As far as I know, the behaviour you are seeing is the default and I am unaware of any third party utilities that can change this.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, this will help you in ungrouping different instances of the same application/window: http://www.windows7news.com/2009/08/26/add-never-combine-hide-labels-to-the-windows-7-taskbar/

> **Add “Never Combine, Hide Labels” to the Windows 7 Taskbar**
>
> Add a string called “MinWidth” to “HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics” and set to 54 then restart. You’ll need to set your taskbar to the “Never Combine” option, but now the program names will always be hidden.

54 is the size of the icons in pixels. Change it to 38 if you use small icons.

You might also find [Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-v2-a-tweak-ui-for-windows-7-vista) useful.

[image]